maven dependency tree verbose - version managed with same version
Following up on this question:
maven dependency tree - version managed
What if the 2 dependencies stated have the same version?
For example, taking the example from above -
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile (version managed from 2.7.2) [INFO] |  |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
I'm seeing this in the output of my project's dependency tree and I was confused about what it meant. Is there any overriding happening here?

The version is managed from a dependency management element, either in the same pom or a parent pom. The meaning is same as explain in the the referenced post

@Ironluca thanks for your reply! meaning that even if the version is managed by a parent pom and it's the same version as the one i specified in my current pom, they will use the same version and the logs above will be printed out?
